# Beamer: Custom counter for frames in the current subsection

Tags: beamer, numbering, counters

I want a frametitle that contains the name of the current subsection, followed by a counter that starts at 1 and increases for every new frame in the current subsection.

I found the following solution somwhere, but my problem is that this counter also increases when I use any form of overlays.

Does someone know how to create a counter that only increases per frame and not per slide? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Subsection counter:
\newcounter{stappen}
\newcommand{\snumreset}{\setcounter{stappen}{0}}
\newcommand{\snum}{\stepcounter{stappen} \Roman{stappen}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}
\snumreset

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\subsecname\snum}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> bla
  \item<2-> counter should not increase
  \item<3-> counter should again not increase
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\subsecname\snum}
  Counter should be at two. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{insub}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{\setcounter{insub}{0}}
\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\addtocounter{insub}{1}}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\subsecname{} - \theinsub}

\begin{document}

\subsection{test}
\begin{frame}{.}
    abc
    \pause 
    cdef
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}{.}
content...
\end{frame}

\subsection{test}
\begin{frame}{.}
    abc
    \pause 
    cdef
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the output PDF looks good but I get two "Undefined control sequence." errors when compiling the tex file.

Comment: @Florian Maybe you have an old beamer version, try with `\usepackage{etoolbox}`. If this does not help, please add the complete error message.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining your own counter, you could use the `frame number` counter, that is not increased with every overlay.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{\Roman{framenumber}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsec 1}


\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\subsecname\insertframenumber}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item<1-> bla
  \item<2-> counter should not increase
  \item<3-> counter should again not increase
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\subsecname\insertframenumber}
  Counter should be at two. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but I would need to reset the framenumber counter at every new subsection, so I would loose the "real" framenumber counter should I need it somewhere else.